# Extending Graphics2D class without implementing all methods

Tags: java, oop, graphics, implementation, graphics2d

I have a class named MyClass and I want this class to extend Graphics2D (in java.awt). However when I type  `public class MyClass extends Graphics2D { .... }` I have to add the unimplemented methods draw, drawImage, addRenderingHints, etc. because Eclipse shows this error and it won't compile.

This is where the question comes to my mind: I just want to use **draw**, **setBackground** and other few methods of Graphics2D, I don't want the rest of the code coming with other unimplemented methods which are mandatory.

Is there a way to avoid this? Because I'm extremely clean and simple when it comes to code and I don't want other 100 lines of code which I don't even use.

What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have it extend Graphics, and whenever you need a Graphics2D, just cast.

`Graphics g = this.create()`;
`Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;`

You'd need to make a Graphics variable within however, as you cannot cast `this`.

So for "setBackground":

```
public void setBackground(Image img) {
    g2d.setBackground(img);
}
```

Really, though, no matter what you do, it's going to be messy. I'm not even sure if you can do the this.create() thing without bad stuff happening, so keep that in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but Graphics class itself has lots of unnecessary (for my purpose) methods too. If I extend Graphics, then I have to include those methods. Right?

Comment: Yup, unfortunately. You'll be better off with some sort of helper class that takes a Graphics2D in it's constructor, then calling methods off of that. Something like: `GraphicsHelper gh = new GraphicsHelper(g2d); gh.doStuff();`

Comment: Can you look my comment for the first reply please? What do you think about using Line2D or do you know some general class that enables to draw line + string at the same time?

Comment: I don't know of any classes that work only with lines and strings. Again, I'd try to avoid extending graphics classes.

Answer (score 3):

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html

Graphics2D is an abstract class, lots of methods are not abstract and all of them must be defined in order to get a subclass that can be instantiated.

If you want to try, you could try extending some class that implements Graphics2D. But then, if you are not careful you will be risking that your implementation of the methods that you want may not be coherent with the methods that you do not override...

Comment: Allright, I'm running away from Graphics2D. Could you suggest an AWT class for drawing a line + string? **Edit:** I know that java.awt.geom.Line2D is good for lines, but what about a line+string?

Comment: Here is a good example, you override paint(Graphics) method from the container http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/141804